# How do I create an 'infix macro' like `\choose`?

Tags: macros

I'd like to write macros like `\choose`, that takes its arguments from the stuff preceding and following its invocation.

For instance, a command `\modulo` that replaces `{A \modulo \sim}` with [`\faktor{A}{\sim}`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/faktor/).

How could that work?

Comment: you can not. tex just has a few fixed constructs that can do this. basically fractions with or without a dividing line , there is no general mechanism to colloect the preceding tokens

Comment: David Carlisle would know better, but I'm pretty sure that such macros are one of the worse parts of TeX: because the macro comes after the argument, you can never be sure of the style of the math you're looking at.

Comment: @Teepeemm not "one of the worst", it is absolutely the worst part of the tex syntax design